# ResultSet to String java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm just after a way to convert a ResultSet to string I've tried:

```
toReturn = result.getString(0);
```

I'm only after a proof that its working and thought this would be all that I need to return it via:

```
writer.write(toReturn);
```

TIA

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html. You need to know what the resultset contains, call next() to go to the first row, and the  call getString() with the appropriate column index. Learn the API before using it blindly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JDBC column indexes start at 1, not zero, so try `result.getString(1)`

Comment: Thanks, but still no joy, if I comment out the line:

toReturn = result.getString(1);

It works, but as soon as it put that in I get an error?

Answer (score 0):

if toReturn is a string, then calling getString(indx) will return a string and you will get an error on that line if it was assigning a different type.